# How to get full browser url in next js, getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Now, i'm in `http://localhost:3000/`, but on prod i will be in a different url, for example `http://example.com/`, how can i get full browser url in getServerSideProps? I have to get `http://localhost:3000/` or `http://example.com/`, if string will not contain port, it will be ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And in the additional answer you use in this my case :

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext
) => {
  const { req } = context;
  let url = req.headers.referer;
  let arr = url.split('/');
  url = `${arr[0]}//${arr[2]}`;
```

This URL gives you for example http://localhost:3000 enjoy!

Comment: My `req.headers` not have properties **referer**. Just host, connection, pragma, accept and cookie.

Comment: This has a little fallback as it wont catch the URL upon refresh

Answer (score -5):

'next/router' provide a couple of methods too, which you can use. For example:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const RouterObject = () => {
  const { asPath, pathname, req, query, res } = useRouter();
  console.log(asPath);
  console.log(pathname); 
  console.log('host: ', req.headers.host);
}
```

If you have the host you can check if contains localhost. Then you know you are in your local environment.

Comment: @НиколайКраснов `useRouter` is a custom React hook and can't be used inside `getServerSideProps`. It also does not return `req` or `res` objects.

Comment: Why has the OP chose this answer is baffling me.